# sh: ,: unknown operand. Docker and Vite ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, vite

I have set up my ReactJs with Vite, Dockerized it. But when i run `docker-compose up`, I get this:

```bash
[+] Building 0.0s (0/0)                                                                                                                  
[+] Running 1/0
 ✔ Container frontend_svc  Created                                                                                                  0.0s 
Attaching to frontend_svc
frontend_svc  | sh: ,: unknown operand
frontend_svc exited with code 2
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18.16.1-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm i

COPY . .

EXPOSE 5173

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

and `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: 'frontend_svc'
    ports:
      - 5173:5173
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    stdin_open: true
```

My react project is default Vite ReactJs. I haven't edited it.

I'm a beginner in Docker, maybe a did something wrong

Comment: That looks like the error you get if `CMD` isn't actually a JSON array.  What's in the question looks right; can you double-check that your actual Dockerfile contains only ASCII spaces U+0020 and "straight" quotes U+0022?